# How to get Average in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

How can I select all products, their name, average star rating, and most recent rating date? The results should be in descending order of average star rating.

This is the query I've written so far:

```
SELECT product_name, avg_star_rating, recent_rating_date
FROM product
ORDER BY avg_star_rating DESC
```

and these are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE product
(prod_id varchar(15),
product_name varchar(30),
product_price double precision,
product_manufacturer varchar(30),
primary key (prod_id)
)
CREATE TABLE customer
(cust_id varchar(15),
customer_name varchar (30),
customer_adress varchar (30),
primary key (cust_id)
)
CREATE TABLE rating
(prod_id,
cust_id,
rating_date date not null,
rating_stars int (5),
primary key (rating_date),
foreign key (prod_id) REFERENCES Products(prod_id),
foreign key (cust_id) REFERENCES customer(cust_id)
)
CREATE TABLE sale
(sale_id,
prod_id,
cust_id,
sale_quantity int,
sale_cost double precision,
primary key (sale_id),
foreign key (prod_id) REFERENCES Products(prod_id),
foreign key (cust_id) REFERENCES customer(cust_id)
)
```

Comment: I don't know how to query those i only managed to do first quesstion

Comment: sorry its my first time to use stack overflow so i have problems wirth c and d i managed to do b SELECT product_name
FROM product
WHERE product.prod_id IN ( SELECT prod_id FROM rating WHERE rating.rating_stars >= 3 )

Comment: Please post sample data, and table schema so someone will be able to assist. Also you are using mysql or sqlite?

Comment: Please tag only one DBMS.

Comment: `database` is not a useful tag. There are numerous databases; mysql, sql-server, sqlite, postgres, nosql, as a starting list. Please tag the system you are using and add information about your table(s).